# Использование простого класса при запросе MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Доброго всем времени суток господа

В наше время стало 'не модно' использовать запросы типа:

```
$zapros = "DELETE/INSERT INTO/SELECT/UPDATE";
$massiv = mysql_query($zapros,$db_connect);
//$massiv - возвращает или массив, или ответ true/false
```

Сейчас 'модно' делать запросы через класс. В интернете куда не плюнь, любой пример обязательно с извратом от разработчика.

Может ли кто привести в пример очень простого класса, и пример его использования, что бы так сказать 'безболезненно' перейти на запросы использующие подключение через классы?

Comment: Это не "модно", это необходимость.

Функции mysql_* уже depercated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    class db {
        private $connection;

        function connect($host, $user, $pass, $name, $charset = 'utf8') {
            $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$name.';host='.$host;
            try {
                $this->connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES '.$charset));
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                die('Не могу подключиться к базе данных ['.$host.' - '.$name.']<br>'.$e->getMessage());
            }
        }

        function get($sql, $fetch = false, $data = false) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
                $query->execute($data);
            } else {
                $query = $this->connection->query($sql);
            }

            if (!$query) return false;
            $query->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            return ($fetch) ? $query->fetch() : $query->fetchAll();
        }

        function set($sql, $data = false) {
            if (is_array($data)) {
                $query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);
                $result = $query->execute($data);
                if (!$result) return false;
                return $query->rowCount();
            } else {
                $query = $this->connection->query($sql);
                return $query ? $query->rowCount() : false;
            }
        }
```

Примеры использования:

```
 $db = new db();
 $db->connect('localhost', 'root', 'password');
 $users = $db->get('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=:id OR `login`=:login', true, array('id' => 2, 'login' => 'stasQa'));
 var_dump($users);
 $user = $db->get('SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id`=1');
 var_dump($user);
 $db->set('UPDATE `users` SET `login`=:login WHERE `id`=:id', array('id' => 1, 'login' => 'hashcode'));
```

Comment: Вау! Нот бэд.. Попробую укоротить для себя

Comment: только не понятно несколько вещей, чего-бы `connect()` не назвать `__construct()` и почему-бы не наследовать класс PDO ?

Comment: можно пару вопросов?

1. какую часть из этого можно подключить 1 раз, и какую нужно писать при запросе? (я так понял при запросе все, что начинается с объекта?)

2. var_dump($user); - это простите что? o_O в том плане, что и без этого работает